# screen shots for app store submission

Tags: iphone

1. Do I have to submit both portrait and landscape screenshots?
2. Is it fine for my app to only support portrait mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Enough just a portrait screen shot - I submitted the app like that.
2. Yes, no worries about that :)

Best of all [this](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf) document (perhaps you already saw it) tells about all of this.

Comment: there were cases recently when apps were rejected for supporting only one portrait and not both! it basically doesn't cost anything to support both portrait orientation.

Comment: There's no official restriction to the 'one mode' apps. The fact that their apps were rejected is more a thing of UI Design patterns most likely - kinda subjective thing, but they could refuse app.. More about ui design patterns one can read here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/MobileHIG.pdf. And just in case: '-1' is not from me :)

Comment: Again - it costs nothing to support two modes. If there is a slight chance the app will be rejected (wanna try to discuss with Apple _their_ rules? be my guest :)) - I would try to avoid it.

Comment: @sha Uhhhhh, the cost can be minuscule or enormous for supporting both modes. Many apps would require complete UI redesign to support the other mode they do not work in. To put it in perspective, with code that was already abstracted to support dynamic orientation, it took me 2 weeks to get the UI to be adjustable to portrait mode.

Comment: I'm not talking about landscape mode! I'm talking about portrait up-side down

Answer (score 2):

Portrait mode only should be fine. I have app in app store that supports only portrait mode.

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshots can be in any orientation you want. No specific requirement. Although I think now they have to be 640x960 for iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

You can upload screenshots in what ever orientation you want, and yes its okay to only support portrait mode in your app.